# SharePoint Web Service XML - Lookup columns bringing ;#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, sharepoint

When I am using the Lists.asmx webservice to bring out List data, the xml thus generated comes back with list lookup columns with data that look like this: [135;#Superman]

Is there a way to get rid of the Number;# and just leave Superman?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match("1236;#xxl", "\d+;#(.*)").Groups[1]);`

Or use any other string manipulation